# Keep text formatting when submit from html form (textarea)

Tags: php, html

How Can I keep text formatting after using "submit" button in HTML to send result?

```
<textarea id="1" name="scenario" style="width: 300px; height: 50px;"></textarea>

<button type="submit">Send</button>

echo 'scenario: '.$_POST['scenario'].'</br>';
```

Comment: text formatting for what for which element, provide some code or screenshots.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br

Comment: I guess you are looking for textarea formatting please use http://ckeditor.com/demo

Answer (score 2):

**Replace all line breaks with html `br` in your output/echo:**

```
<textarea id="1" name="scenario" style="width: 300px; height: 50px;"></textarea>
<button type="submit">Send</button>
echo 'scenario: '.nl2br($_POST['scenario']).'</br>';
```

**Also, you could give `pre` tags a try (this will preserve indentation also):**

```
echo 'scenario: <pre>'.$_POST['scenario'].'</pre></br>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try nl2br();

```
 <?php
    echo nl2br($string_var);
 ?>
```